# Which package is good for bluetooth in Flutter

Tags: flutter, raspberry-pi, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

I trying to built project using **flutter** and **raspberry pi**. I wanna connect flutter project with raspberry pi using bluetooth,  and I need send data in **.json** file. Please give some suggestion which package is better for both **android** and **ios**.

Answer (score 0):

Try those BLE packages, they are best

https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_blue

https://pub.dev/packages/quick_blue

https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_blue_plugin

From quick_ble package have following features

- Scan BLE peripheral
- Connect BLE peripheral
- Discover services of BLE peripheral
- Transfer data between BLE central & peripheral

Comment: Do you have a experience with this package?

Comment: yes,I have use some packages

Comment: how you show devices real name?